# SharePoint 2013 REST API: how to filter and display fields from a document library?

Tags: 2013, document-library, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm new to the SharePoint REST API. I have a document library with a lot of documents in it and a lot of metadata fields for those documents. I want to filter and display the items in the library the same way you would with a list using the SharePoint REST API. I can't seem to find how to do that in the Microsoft Dev Center.

I tried the following REST call, and it doesn't return an error but it doesn't seem to return any data either. 
/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('DocumentLibraryTitle')/items

Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: a document library essentially is a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That call is correct, did you check the result in a navigator? That should return a JSON.
Just to be sure, your call should be

```
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List Nam')/items",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.d.results);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: I've been testing calls in the browser (just through the URL). I was expecting to see the results displayed there. I'm waiting for my IT department to install Fiddler so I can see the results through that. Thanks confirming it for though.

Comment: I recomend you chrome to test rest calls, IE is quite an idiot and you have to configure some stuff to see it

Comment: Yes, go to your IE Tools -> Content and turn on feed reading view from the Feed and Web Slice Settings.

Comment: I've got feed reading turned on in IE, but all I'm seeing is this:
http://imgur.com/a/bVrn5

Answer (score 0):

- Use Chrome
- Install the [SharePoint Insider extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sharepoint-insider/gjckpigahcbffmeofjfedlffddhfidhj?hl=en)
- Play
- Learn
- then code

[image]

*PS. Code before Play will take you ages..*